# Should openlayers-2 and openlayers be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Most questions up till now used [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) to refer to [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2). With increasing interest in [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3), we will see more questions on this topic. The two versions are so different that answers for one won't be helpful for the other. I therefore suggest the following synonym to make the version explicit:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/openlayers-2/synonyms

Comment: I guess I might be careful about making it a synonym vs burninating the tag (or whatever it's called, a merge first?). If people just type in 'openlayers' and it gets remapped to 2 when they really should have said 3, it's just more editing and confusion. Yes, I know it shows you choices, but not everyone picks, they frequently just type and return.

Comment: @ChrisW With mod privileges synonymizing is easy, merge is too, but burnination needs much more justification and SE involvement so I would perhaps suggest synonym initially, and assuming it works for us, then merge a little later.  Burnination is probably overkill - we have only used that for gis, geospatial and spatial so far.

Comment: I think we should proceed to implement this - nearly 60 views, at least 5 supporters, and no dissent - and [tag:openlayers] is being used potentially ambiguously about 20 times per week.  To find questions that are likely to need removal of the openlayers/openlayers-2 tag we can search using http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2+openlayers-3

Comment: I've suggested a change to the [tag:openlayers] description. Currently, it has a generic description, just like [tag:python] or [tag:qgis] that would suggest it could be used in conjunction with a version specific tag. In reality, the site is automatically mapping it to [tag:openlayers-2], and I'm seeing an increasing misuse of [tag:openlayers-2] on questions that are about version 3 due that behavior.

Comment: So, are the tags not going to be merged? I see the openlayers still creating confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it may necessitate [some retagging of OpenLayers 3 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bopenlayers%5D%20%22openlayers%203%22) tagged [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) I think the effort will be worth it.

Now that the tag synonym has been proposed by @Underdark at https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/openlayers-2/synonyms, and upvoted by me there, I will be very interested to see if we have enough people with sufficient [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) reputation to get this through (or squash it) without us needing to use a moderator tool.

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes)
>   of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will
>   be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and
>   automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.