# Is it time to make [openlayers] tag synonym of [openlayers-3] instead of [openlayers-2]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

18 months ago we made the [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) tag a synonym of [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) as a result of [Should openlayers-2 and openlayers be synonyms?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/should-openlayers-2-and-openlayers-be-synonyms)

Although I am not an OpenLayers user, it now seems to me that most OpenLayers questions are about OpenLayers-3.  Consequently, I think that it is time to redirect the [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) tag to be a synonym of [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3).

If this gets approval to be implemented then, frequently at first, you may find OpenLayers 2 questions when searching using the [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3) tag, and if you do, then I would encourage you while editing them to replace the [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) tag with [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2).

Should we make the [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) tag a synonym of [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3) (instead of [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2))?

Comment: With what seems to be 8 votes for and none against, [tag:openlayers] is now a synonym of [tag:openlayers-3].

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
I've re-tagged my fair share of questions that are tagged improperly because of this (I even found a few more after seeing this question).

The usage guidance will need to be updated (emphasis mine):

> OpenLayers is a JavaScript library for creating dynamic map widgets for web sites. **Use this tag for questions specific to Version 2 of the OpenLayers Javascript client toolkit.**

Or, make [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) a stand alone tag again.
I think this also points out how tag synonyms are confusing when you are asking a question. Outside of putting something in the usage guidance (which many seem to ignore anyway), there's no way of telling that a tag is a synonym.

If I were to submit this question, it would end up with [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) and [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3):

[image: OL Tags while asking]

And, worse, this pattern makes perfect sense for other tags on our site, such as [questions tagged with both qgis and a version tag, like qgis-2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bqgis%5D+%5Bqgis-2.8%5D)

Comment: Isn't eliminating [openlayers] an option? I mean we would stick with ol2 or ol3. Or proceed as you suggest in the last paragraph; the current way seems inappropriate, because when there is ol4 there will be more confusion, right?

Comment: I agree that choosing tags can be confusing, especially for new users, which is why I rank them as the least important of the three parts to a question at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115  I think it is the top answerers of questions in a topic area (e.g. OpenLayers, QGIS, ArcGIS, etc) that should be listened to the most when trying to decide how they should be tagged (so that they can find the ones they want to answer easily and reliably): http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3740/115

Comment: The QGIS tagging Q&A did not result in clear consensus on a way forward (at the time) at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/double-tags-qgis-and-qgis-2-0 but it currently seems to be heading in the direction of making its version tags synonyms of the generic [tag:qgis].

Comment: I've just implemented the redirected synonymy proposed in my question and endorsed by your answer.

Comment: That qgis post has a +8 score answer; so at least today there is a consensus.

Comment: I think it was too soon to implement this suggestion, because there was little time since the Q was asked, because there was few votes, and because there were two different solutions in the answer, and the one it was implemented was the one OP agreed. I for example, support the last suggestion (making openlayers stand alone) or buninating it. The synonym suggestion is temporary, because when a ol4 tag appears it will cause confusion again. @PolyGeo

Comment: Perhaps what I did not understand yet is why should openlayers be treated differently from arcgis and qgis when it comes to tagging; i.e; why can't it have a master tag and version tags? Or if a master tag is useless why not burninating it, just in case someone is willing to lead the activity?

Comment: @AndreSilva I implemented this after three days because the simple switch of what version of OpenLayers the [tag:openlayers] tag points to is trivial to change (and trivial to change back), and was in line with the momentum from that earlier Q&A that this one was asked in order to validate.  I did not implement a merge because that did not have the endorsement of the earlier Q&A nor this one.  Burnination of the [tag:openlayers] tag was not endorsed nor discussed except in passing during either Q&A (yet).

Comment: I had also overlooked the votes from question. @PolyGeo.

Comment: @AndreSilva ArcGIS, OpenLayers and QGIS questions are answered by three different sets of our users.  There is some overlap, of course, but not much between the Top Answerers of each.  I think questions are best tagged using schemes that suit their most likely potential answerers.  The tagging guidelines which I think work well for software of the ArcGIS platform have not been reflected in the tagging schemes endorsed by the other two sub-communities.  I think there is room for our sub-communities to decide upon the tagging schemes that they think will work best for them.

Answer (score 0):

I alluded to an alternative to the proposal in my question, in an 18 month old [comment](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/should-openlayers-2-and-openlayers-be-synonyms#comment6747_3914) on [Should openlayers-2 and openlayers be synonyms?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/should-openlayers-2-and-openlayers-be-synonyms):

> With mod privileges synonymizing is easy, merge is too, but
>   burnination needs much more justification and SE involvement so I
>   would perhaps suggest synonym initially, and assuming it works for us,
>   then merge a little later. Burnination is probably overkill - we have
>   only used that for gis, geospatial and spatial [and arcgis] so far.

Instead of simply switching the OpenLayers synonym from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3, I think it would be better to use these steps:

1. Merge [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) into [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) with the latter being the master
2. Break (or don't make - it's a checkbox in the mod tool for merging) the synonymy between [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) and [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2)
3. Make a synonym from [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) to [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3)

Burnination of [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) to eliminate the need for step 3 is possible but I think overkill.

The above 3 steps would mean that when anyone tries to tag a question as [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) it will be assumed they meant [openlayers-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3), which I *think* seems reasonable today and until OpenLayers 4 starts to pervade.